# Button alignments of HTML page get upset in mobile view

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

I have included some buttons to a div it can properly view from pc browser. But in mobile browser it is not showing properly.

SS of the mobile view

[image: Screen Shot of mobile view]

SS of a PC view

[image: Screen Shot of pc browser]

```
//CSS code
.tools {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    height: 30px;
    top: 7px;
}
.tools button {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 4px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}


//HTML code
<div class="tools">
    <button id="btnRun" mode=1 onclick="runCode();">Run</button>
    <button id="btnClearOutput" onclick="clearOutput();">Clear</button>
    <button title="Open a file" onclick="openFile();">Open</button>
    <button title="Save code" onclick="saveCode();">Save</button>
    <button onclick="toggleTheme();">Theme</button>
    <button id="btnRaise" onclick="raise();">Raise &#x270B</button>
</div>
```

I want all buttons in one line like in PC view. And also PC view contain a problem. The raise button which have a emoji in its text not vertically aligned properly.

What should I do for solving this issue ?

P.S.
Sorry for mentioning this before. I have set meta tag like below
`<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>`
when I remove that all above problems solved. But then page not initially zoom to fit to window. But I want to fit to window.

Thank you

Comment: inspect your tools class and check might be tools class don't have 100% width,

Comment: the width of that div is more than 360 so only its coming like this in mbile u need to right media query to reduce width or make it center in mobile version

Comment: @NoumanAhmed thanks for the reply. I have updated the question. Do you have any further Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your outer div of tools is creating some padding at the right which is not giving enough space for the last button. Try to inspect if you have such padding.

**Suggestion:** Try creating the same layout with a flexbox or grid for better responsiveness and control.

Answer (score 0):

```
.tools button {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 4px 10px;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 480px ){
  .tools button {
    padding: 4px 4px;
  }
}
```